jq returns null or error when parsing json response
When parsing a json response using jq run from cmd.exe on a Windows 10 machine, I always get either a null response or an error when trying to get a value present in the JSON.
Here is the curl:
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" --compressed -d "{\"upc\": \"4002293401102\"}" "https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup" | jq ".ean"

Here is the JSON response. For brevity, I shortened the full response as it's quite long.
{
  "code": "OK",
  "total": 1,
  "offset": 0,
  "items": [
    {
      "ean": "4002293401102",
      "title": "Wusthof Gourmet 3-Inch Serrated Paring Knife",
      "asin": "B0000DJYE3",
      "elid": "192088094351"
    }
  ]
}

Here is what I've tried in jq to obtain the EAN value. In parenthesis I put abbreviated errors I receive.

jq ".items.ean" (I get: jq: error (at :0): Cannot index array with string "ean")
jq "[items].ean" (I get: curl: Failed writing body)
jq ".[items].ean" (I get: curl: Failed writing body)
jq "[].items.ean" (I get: jq: error (at :0): Cannot index array with string "items")
jq "[].[items].ean" (I get: curl: Failed writing body)
jq ".items.[ean]" (I get: curl: Failed writing body"

I'm sure I'm using the wrong syntax for jq. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I just cannot seem to get the syntax of getting that value.

.items[].ean.

Hi Jeff, when I tried  jq ".items[ean]"  it returned: jq: error: ean/0 is not defined at , line 1:

You must have mistyped it, or else perhaps you are running a really old version of jq. I can reproduce the error with ".items[] | ean" but that's not what he wrote.

My apologies...I can tell I've been up way too long. lol It now works using:  jq ".items[].ean". When trying it out from Jeff Mercado I simply typed it in wrong on my end. Thank you so much!
